# Delegate not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I am trying to pass some information between a subview and a parentview on the navigation stack using delegates.

However for some reason when the I execute the delegate from the subview then pop the subview from the navigational controller it never enters the delegate method that is set up in the parent view.. I have tried NSLogs & Breakpoints the thread is defiantly not making it to this delegate method in the main view so I was hoping you could help me out.

First Of all I will show you how I have set up my delegate, where I call it in my subview and then where I set it up in the mainview hopefully you guys will be able to see something I have not so far.

Subview.h // I have left out things not related to the delegate

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//Delegate - Protocol stuff for passing data from this view to the parent view
@protocol PassSearchData <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSArray *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource> {
//Delegate (Used to pass information back to parent view)
    id <PassSearchData> delegate;
}
//Delegate (Used to pass information back to parent view)
@property (strong) id delegate;
@end
```

SecondView.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

//..

//Delegate (Used to pass information back to parent view)
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    //Access selected cells content (cell.textLabel.text)
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Parent view logic (sends info back to the correct cell in parent view)
    if (parentViewSelectedIndexPath.section == 0) 
    {
        if (parentViewSelectedIndexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            //Predicates restrict the values that will be returned from the query
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"MANUFACTURER",cell.textLabel.text];
            filterArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            [[self delegate]setManufactureSearchFields:filterArray withIndexPath:indexPath]; 

//            NSLog(@"Filtered Array = %@", filterArray);
        }
    }
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //pops current view from the navigatoin stack

}//...
```

Then this is how I set it up inside the FirstViewController

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VehicleResultViewController.h" //With this included I can now use the PassSearchData delegates of this view for passing data

@interface VehicleSearchViewController : UITableViewController <PassSearchData> {
//..
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "VehicleSearchViewController.h"
#import "VehicleResultViewController.h" //Subview

//..

#pragma mark - Received data from Sub view delegates

//These are the delegate method for passing data from the child to the parent view (parent being this view, with the delegate being declared in the subview)

- (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSArray *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
{
    manufactureSearchObjectString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"] objectAtIndex:0];
    manufactureIdString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURERID"] objectAtIndex:0]; //Restricts Models dataset
    manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
}
```

If anyone knows what I'm missing/doing wrong any help would be really really heapful

any questions let me know.

**Solution**

In the firstviewcontroller when I go to load the secondviewcontroller inside 
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I forgot to set the secondviewcontrollers delegate before I pushed the view to the navigational stack.. so the missing code was this.

FirstView.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Get the subview ready for use
        VehicleResultViewController *vehicleResultViewController = [[VehicleResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VehicleResultViewController" bundle:nil];

        //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vehicleResultViewController animated:YES];

        [vehicleResultViewController setDelegate:self];

//etc
```

thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first, your delegate should be a weak reference to avoid retain cycles.  But I suspect maybe the delegate isn't getting set.  Can you show the code where SecondViewController is instantiated and the delegate is set?  Can you set a breakpoint at the delegate call and verify that it is not nil?

Comment: okay I changed my reference to weak but now I'm getting this weird error. **Existing ivar 'delegate' for _weak property 'delegate' must be _weak** Also I'm not 100% sure on what you are referring to where you ask me to show you the code where the SecondViewController is instantiated and the delegate is set.. are you referring to when I load the secondviewcontroller onto the navigation stack from the firstviewcontroller?

Comment: thats exactly what you were referring too.. I have fixed the issue now with the solution added above.. thankyou very much for the help... totally managed to fluff that one up myself lol.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  Did you get the _weak ivar reference solved too?  You might try removing the ivar declaration and letting the compiler generate it for you.  You should also add the <PassSearchData> after id on the property declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not setting Delegate.
After Creation Instanace(object)of SecondViewController ,you have to set Delegate.

ie

```
SecondViewController *secondObj=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"> bundle:nil];

 [secondObj setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: indeed the issue here was that fact I had not set the delegate. thankyou for your help.